# lower semicontinuity of the number of extreme points

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, convexity, semicontinuity

Do you know the reference for the following fact:

the number of extreme points of a compact convex
subset of a locally compact space varies lower semicontinuously when we endow the space of compact sets with Hausdorff metric?

It is not very hard to prove it but I would prefer to cite it and I am pretty sure that it is already shown. I would be grateful for some hints where to find it...